position fixed скрывает все элементы
Всем привет. Я пытаюсь реализовать вертикальный слайдер
Код index.html


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider__section {
  width: 100%;
}

.header__nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header__nav ul li {
  margin-right: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  position: fixed;
}

.header__nav ul li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.section__wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}
<div class="header__nav">
  <ul>
    <li data-slide-to="1">First Page</li>
    <li data-slide-to="2">Second Page</li>
    <li data-slide-to="3">Three Page</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="slider__section">
  <div class="section__wrapper">
    <div class="section__inner">
      <div style="background-color: rebeccapurple" class="section"></div>
      <div style="background-color: red" class="section"></div>
      <div style="background-color: rgb(24, 24, 180)" class="section"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



При указании позиции fixed элементы header__nav оказываются за slider__section и при этом тесно наслоены друг на друге.
Мне нужно что бы меню было видно и оно было в фиксированном положении.
Буду благодарен. Спасибо

Как минимум, сделайте фиксированное позиционирование не для каждого пукта меню, а для их родительского блока. Т.е. перенесите position: fixed; из .header__nav ul li в .header__nav ul

Спасибо друг. Получилось



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider__section {
  width: 100%;
}

.header__nav {
  position: fixed;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header__nav ul li {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.section__wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 175px;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 3s;
}
<div class="header__nav">
  <ul>
    <li onclick="slid_1.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})" data-slide-to="1">First Page</li>
    <li onclick="slid_2.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})" data-slide-to="2">Second Page</li>
    <li onclick="slid_3.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})" data-slide-to="3">Three Page</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="slider__section">
  <div class="section__wrapper">
    <div class="section__inner">
      <div id="slid_1" style="background-color: rebeccapurple" class="section">
        slid_1
      </div>
      <div id="slid_2" style="background-color: red" class="section">
        slid_2
      </div>
      <div id="slid_3" style="background-color: rgb(24, 24, 180)" class="section">
        slid_3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Спасибо дружище!
